# Disabling the dropdownlist if no value and move to load next dropdownlist

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have 4 dropdown list using ajax. I works fine if values were found on each respective dropdown.

But if there is no value in 3rd dropdown it doesn't load to 4th automatically and doesn't disable 3rd dropdown either. Insted, I get a blank option to choose from 3rd dropdown, which if I select then it loads 4th dropdown.

Ajax Code:

```js
function selectState(country_id){
 if(country_id!="0"){
  loadData('state',country_id);
  $("#region_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select Region</option>");
 }else{
  $("#state_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select state</option>");
  $("#region_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select Region</option>");
 }
}
function selectRegion(state_id){
 if(state_id!="0"){
  loadData('region',state_id);
  $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select city</option>");
 }else{
  $("#region_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select Region</option>");
  $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select city</option>");
 }
}
function selectCity(state_region_id){
 if(state_region_id!="0"){
  loadData('city',state_region_id);
 }else{
  $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select city</option>");
 }
}

 var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
 $("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
    $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).html('Please wait... <img src="http://localhost/admin/includes/images/loading.gif" />');
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "loadData",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
   $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
   $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='0'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");  
   $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);  
  }
 });
}
```

And View:

```
<?php if($list->num_rows() > 0){ ?>
<select class="full-width" name="v_item_country" onchange="selectState(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="0">Country</option>
    <?php foreach($list->result() as $listElement): ?>
        <option value="<?= $listElement->v_country_id?>"><?= $listElement->v_country_name?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<select class="full-width" name="v_item_state" id="state_dropdown" onchange="selectRegion(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="0">State</option>
</select>
<select class="full-width" name="v_item_region" id="region_dropdown" onchange="selectCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="0">Region</option>
</select>
<select class="full-width" name="v_item_city" id="city_dropdown">
    <option value="0">City</option>
</select>
<?php }else{ echo 'No Country Name Found'; } ?>
```

And Controller:

```
public function loadData()
{
    $loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
    $loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

    $this->load->model('admin/model_users');
    $result=$this->model_users->getData($loadType,$loadId);
    $HTML="";

    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result->result() as $list){
            $HTML.="<option value='".$list->id."'>".$list->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    echo $HTML;
}
```

Model:

```
function getCountry(){
    $this->db->select('v_country_id,v_country_name');
    $this->db->from('vbc_country');
    $this->db->order_by('v_country_name', 'asc'); 
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query; 
}
function getData($loadType,$loadId){
    if($loadType=="state"){
        $fieldList='id,v_state_name as name';
        $table='vbc_state';
        $fieldName='country_id';
        $orderByField='v_state_name';                       
    }elseif($loadType == "region"){
        $fieldList='id,v_state_region_name as name';
        $table='vbc_state_region';
        $fieldName='state_id';
        $orderByField='v_state_region_name';
    }else{
        $fieldList='id,v_city_name as name';
        $table='vbc_city';
        $fieldName='state_region_id';
        $orderByField='v_city_name';
    }
    $this->db->select($fieldList);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
    $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query; 
}
```

Comment: It is half php half jQuery.. not very understandable code and why you are posting the data via ajax? you need to use GET method

Comment: Thanks @IlanHasanov, I have just added some more code to it so that it can be understandable.

Comment: I dnt knw if it would help.. but if u r trying to solve some country sate city situation in a form try this plugin once ... http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function loadData()
{
    $loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
    $loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

    $this->load->model('admin/model_users');
    $result=$this->model_users->getData($loadType,$loadId);
    $HTML="";

    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result->result() as $list){
            $HTML.="<option value='".$list->id."'>".$list->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else {
      $HTML.="<option value='disabled' disabled>No results found...</option>";
    }
    echo $HTML;
}
```

Comment: No luck, didn't work. I think because in the table for regions, I have 3 fields: id, state_id & state_region_name. Even though 3rd field is empty in this case but row still returns 1.

Comment: @CodeIgniter I can tell you that the way you structured this code. is really wrong.

Comment: I am learning.. I got this script off the internet.. It works fine except for what I posted for.